# How to make Numbers accept the "." instead of the comma "," when inserting data?

Tags: numbers

I'm from elgium. In Dutch, as probably in some other languages, you write numbers like this: 3,141592, where in English it'd be 3.141592, but the Numbers app only interprets my input as a number when I use a comma, which messes things up when I export it as a csv. How do I make it accept the . instead of the ,? My system language is already set to English.

Comment: You should be proud to be Flemish from Belgium, not elgium :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers seems to use the decimal separator selected in System Preferences:

[image]

I didn't find any way to use both comma and period as decimal separators though.

Note that if you change the region from the menu at the top, it also affects things like the default values of locale variables in Terminal and iTerm.

Comment: thx a lot. I always find it funny how in Dutch, you use the opposite you use in English.